# ThreeJS error: THREE.FaceNormalsHelper is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working through a course on three.js and ran into this error in Chrome v79 while following along:

> "THREE.FaceNormalsHelper is not a constructor".

The offending line of code looks like this:

```
normals = new THREE.FaceNormalsHelper(sphere, 5, 0x00ff00, 1);
```

The [official three.js documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/helpers/FaceNormalsHelper) gives the following example:

```
helper = new THREE.FaceNormalsHelper( box, 2, 0x00ff00, 1 );
```

The sphere is created with a `SphereGeometry` which is an instance of `Geometry`, so that shouldn't be a problem. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. Please could you point out what I may have overlooked or not considered?

Comment: It looks possible that they've removed FaceNormalsHelper from the codebase, but forgot to toast the docs.  If you search the three.js repo, there's no .js for it, but it looks like there used to be.

Comment: Is ThreeJS properly attached in HTML? 
Before You invoking this constructor?

Comment: Here's a guy modifying FaceNormalsHelper: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/3511/files

But if you look there in the current repo (or search for FaceNormalsHelper.js), you get nothing.

That said, looks like it was a constructor back in its day.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't look at the migration guide. As @Mugen87 points out, it's been moved to the examples directory. Actually it doesn't say that it's been moved, just that it's "now part of the examples.".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FaceNormalsHelper` is not part of the core library anymore since `R112`. This is also mentioned in the [migration guide](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide#r111--r112).

The class is still available in the examples directory. You can import it like so:

```
import { FaceNormalsHelper } from 'three/examples/jsm/helpers/FaceNormalsHelper.js';
```

`three.js R112`

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI: As of 21 Mar 2021, FaceNormalsHelper is gone from the "examples" folder as well.  There's a "VertexNormalsHelper" that might be a replacement, but I'm still too much of a beginner to know for sure.